# What is the best place in SpringBoot application to initialize business logic?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to initialize some business logic (e.g. send some messages to a message broker) in a Spring Boot application after context is created and beans (singletons) are initialized - what is the "most correct" place for it?

From my perspective the candidates are:

1. Implement `ApplicationListener` + listen for `ContextStartedEvent`
2. `ApplicationRunner`'s OR `CommandLineRunner`'s `run()` method
3. `@PostConstruct` of a particular bean (I don't this method, but have seen sometimes in colleagues' code - because I need to be sure all beans are created, initialized, customized, set up, etc. and I don't wanna play with beans load order)

I understand that in general, in MVC web application the place for business logic is `@Service`, but I need to call it immediately after the start of my application, so what's the best way to do that?

Comment: This is more or less a meta question, as it does not matter and is a matter of taste. A good design does not couple the business code to the implementation details of the container it is running in; imho this out rules all your "solutions". I would go with another layer of abstraction or with the least invasive solution e.g. `@PostConstruct`. `CommandLineRunner` has another purpose, did you mean `ApplicationRunner`.

Comment: there is no "best" place but you like the most. Spring boot allows you to do same things in different ways

Comment: you can also do it within an BeanPostProcessor. I recommend the ApplicationListener. Spring Boot is doing this as well on startup for databaseinitialization.

Comment: BeanPostProcessor - isn't it risky some another beans' PostProcessors aint completed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with @EventListener. Like you said there are different ways to achieve this. I will give my opinion on your numbers

1. ApplicationListener called 3 times. No need to listen this one. This maybe usefull if you are doing something close to tomcat.
2. ApplicationRunner,CommandLineRunner is called after all bean initialization. This can be useful.
3. @PostConstruct you can get null beans if you are working with other components.

I prepared a small example to use all these in one application and print [some logs](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/spring-lifecycle) but I could not put them here. spring log looks ugly here. anyway my suggestion is [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/master/spring-lifecycle/src/main/java/com/mascix/springlifecycle/EventListenerExampleBean.java) if you dont have any dependency to other beans this looks nicest. if there are dependencies then you can use [ApplicationListener](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/master/spring-lifecycle/src/main/java/com/mascix/springlifecycle/AppStartupListener.java) which was the last logged in my example.

Comment: Thank you for reminding about @EventListener, what is the exact event you recommend to use ( for the purpose described, see my question)

Comment: Well in my example @EventListener called once which was ContextRefreshedEvent but as you see its called once therefore no need to check the event. I tested with direct from command line CTRL+C only sends event to AppStartupListener not others.

Comment: Thank you, why did you select ContextRefreshedEvent  which could be inviked multiple times, rather than ContextStartedEvent which seems crated exactly for context started notifying?

Comment: hmm I did not select that event :) I think you did not read the startup log I put into github. that event was the only one came to ```@EventListener```. I specifically said "no need to check the event" but I dont know your project and just to be careful I would implement ```@EventListener``` and check what events come to your bean and decide after yourself.